# Why Linux df command still showing 100% disk used although I've delete some files. even lsof | grep delete show nothing?

Tags: linux, bash

Using `df -Th` show `/`folder usage 100%:

```
[root@gridtb007 ~]# df -Th
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext4    60G   58G     0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs   24G     0   24G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1      ext4  1008M   62M  896M   7% /boot
/dev/sda6      ext4   183G  188M  173G   1% /scratch
/dev/sda5      ext4   9.7G  150M  9.0G   2% /var/cache/openafs
/dev/sdb1      ext4   917G  526G  346G  61% /data
AFS            afs    8.6G     0  8.6G   0% /afs
```

Then, I delete in `/root` dir, however, `df -TH` still show `/` folder usage 100%. and I use `lsof | grep delete` show the lock process, and I Kill all the showd process, now `lsof | grep delete` show nothing, however, `df -TH` still show `/` folder usage 100%. Then I reboot the server, `df -TH` still show `/` folder usage 100%.  So I don't know how to handle it.

`df -Th /root` shows this:

```
[root@gridtb007 ~]# df -Th /root
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext4   60G   58G     0 100% /
```

Comment: Inspect your root partition. Use the "du" command and see what is eating up space in it. Also, maybe the value of 60 GB is a very small size for what you are running. Use a disk partitioner and enlarge it.

Comment: What does `df -Th /root` tell you?

Comment: @janos I have edited, /root is a dir in / partition

Comment: It's possible that you have something running that keeps filling the disk even while you're deleting stuff. Look for directories that are unusually large, using `du -sm /root/*`, and then in the biggest subfolders, and so on

Comment: By default, 5% of space is reserved for root. `Use%` is the non-reserved part. That means that at 57GB used and beyond, your FS will be shown as 100% full even though you (as root but not as a user) can write another 3GB to it. This also means that if 60GB is used and 3GB is deleted, it'll remain unchanged at 100% (but Used will go down).

Comment: Run `find / -xdev -size +1000000 -ls` to find all large files (>512MiB) on that filesystem. If you have questions about which files can safely be removed, the folks over on http://unix.stackexchange.com can help..

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks, I find the large file on that filesystem, and delete them, it's ok.

Comment: @thatotherguy, Thanks, before I delete some files, maybe not so large, so there is no 5% space reserved for root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like  @that other guy said

> By default, 5% of space is reserved for root. Use% is the non-reserved part

I delete some files that are not so large, so there is still shown 100%. However, just as @Mark Plotnick said

> Run `find / -xdev -size +1000000 -ls` to find all large files (>512MiB) on that filesystem

And then, I delete these large files, the FS show right capacity.

Comment: Also, you can have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140367/finding-all-large-files-in-the-root-filesystem for more detailed answer. It will also tell you how to sort the result by size.